# Open MP program not computing all work from its Workqueue

Tags: c, multithreading, openmp

I have an omp program which is supposed to compute all work from a queue which is filled when a thread is idling dynamically. My problem is that after finishing the parallel section the work queue is not empty how it is supposed to be.

I count the number of work with workNum which is the size of the workqueue available_gridsQ.
After one thread finishes his work hes put into an idling state which is also queued in thread_idleQ so the longest waiting thread gets work when available.

When number of idling Threads is equal to number of total initialized threads and there is no work the program finishes.

computeGrid is the computation function which takes some time and calls attemptGridCache within to split the work.

```
double solutionFindTime;
double start_time;

grids_queue* available_gridsQ = NULL;
num_queue* thread_idleQ = NULL;
int workNum = 0;
int initGridsNum;
int idling_threadsNum = 0;
int threadNum;

int attemptGridCache(struct grid sudokuGrid) // Adds more work to the work queue (available_gridsQ)
{
    int localGridsNum;
    int localIdlingNum;
    #pragma omp critical
    {
        localGridsNum = workNum;
        localIdlingNum = idling_threadsNum;
    }
    if (localGridsNum < localIdlingNum)
    {
        workNum++;
        enqueue_cpy(&available_gridsQ, sudokuGrid);
        return 1;
    }
    else return 0;
}

void computeGrid(int* count, double* computeTime)
{
    struct grid nextSudoku;
    #pragma omp critical
        nextSudoku = dequeue(&available_gridsQ);
    if (nextSudoku.size > 0) // There is work in the queue otherwise return
    {
        #pragma omp atomic
            (*count) -= 1;
        double t = omp_get_wtime();
        if (solveSudoku(&nextSudoku, 0, 0, NULL, NULL) == 1)
            solutionFindTime = omp_get_wtime() - start_time;

        t = omp_get_wtime() - t;
        (*computeTime) += t;
        free(nextSudoku.sudoku);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    double end_time;
    double duration;
    double initDuration;

    threadNum = atoi(argv[1]);
    char* file = argv[2];
    omp_set_num_threads(threadNum);
    start_time = omp_get_wtime();

    if (threadNum == 0)
        return 0;

    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        // First Thread initializes first sudoku grids to compute
        #pragma omp single
        {
            double startInit_time = omp_get_wtime();
            available_gridsQ = initParallel(threadNum, &initGridsNum, file);
            initDuration = omp_get_wtime() - startInit_time;
        }
        
        double totalComputeTime = 0;

        struct grid nextSudoku;
        // compute Init Sudokus first
        while (initGridsNum > 0)
            computeGrid(&initGridsNum, &totalComputeTime);

        idling_threadsNum++;
        #pragma omp critical
            intEnqueue(&thread_idleQ, omp_get_thread_num());

        do {
            //read
            if (workNum > 0 && intDequeue(&thread_idleQ, 0) == omp_get_thread_num()) // Get first idling thread without freeing queue (I think this should be ok because of the queue->no critical section)
            {
                idling_threadsNum--;
                computeGrid(&workNum, &totalComputeTime);
                intDequeue(&thread_idleQ, 1);
                idling_threadsNum++;
                intEnqueue(&thread_idleQ, omp_get_thread_num());
            }

        } while (idling_threadsNum < threadNum && workNum > 0); // This could cause the problem, how would I make it blocked?

        printf("took %f seconds to compute w thread %i \n", totalComputeTime, omp_get_thread_num());
    }

    printf("Left Work %i\n", workNum); // Output is greater than 0 ! <-----------
    end_time = omp_get_wtime();

    duration = end_time - start_time;
    printf("%f\n", duration);
    printf("%f\n", solutionFindTime);
    printf("%f\n", initDuration);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you have a large number of race conditions, such as `idling_threadsNum++;`. Why are you doing the thread management yourself? This sounds like a great application for OpenMP tasks.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout could u give me an example? Do I need a master Thread for this?

Comment: Read a tutorial. Where did you learn OpenMP? I'm pretty sure whatever book or website you used also has information about tasks.